# SQL Server Express R2 database size limitation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

As you know, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express supports 10GB.

So What happens if I try to attach a file which's size is more than 10GB?

choices,

A- warn me before trying to attach and stop attaching.

B- attach 10gb of file and then warn me about "can not attach anymore".

Comment: Why don you, you know, just **TRY IT**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B makes no sense.  Are you suggesting it would stop mid-field and just leave it hanging?

Attaching a database does not involve processing transactions - it's all or nothing.